# Regex for cell phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be a proper regular expression for JavaScript to cover cell phone number like the following?

```
000-00-0000
```

Comment: The answer is very easy to find on the Interwebs as well as on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phone+number+regex+javascript), did you do *any* research before asking?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *\d* is shorthand for a digit so I'd go with something like this:

```
var pattern = /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/;
if(orig_input.match(pattern)) {
    //do stuff...
}
```

However, and this is because I have no idea how phone-numbers look in your country id probably also go with something else in the last part since the length of that probably can differ so lets say that the minimum is 4 digits and the maximum is six then I'd do something like this.

```
var pattern = /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4,6}$/;
if(orig_input.match(pattern)) {
    //do stuff...
}
```

Notice the last part in the regular expression \d{4,6}.

Also this isn't a very tricky question so listen to the community (the comments) and try to google stuff like this in the future, you'll always learn more if you figure stuff out by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/
```

Or shorter:

```
/^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/
```